# Accessing an item of an array with jquery?

Tags: jquery

How would I access the div with a text node of 2?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($('.content').length);

  $('.content').click(function(e) {
// ...
  })
});
</script>

<div class='content'>1</div>

<div class='content'>2</div>

<div class='content'>3</div>

<div class='content'>4</div>
```

Comment: If you mean when you click on it, use `this` or `e.target` in your click function: `alert($(this).html())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on whether that's your only HTML or not.  If your items only contain single digits, `contains` will work.  If not, you'll need to filter based on the content.

```
$('.content').filter( function() { return $(this).text() == '2'; } )
             ...
```

On the other hand if you just want the second element, regardless of content, you can use `eq()`.

```
$('.content').eq(2)
             ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.filter()` in conjunction with `.text()` to get a jQuery object which contains all elements whose text content equals 2 (rather than `:contains`, which also matches elements which are not onyl composed of `2` characters)

```
var divContaining2 = $('.content').filter(function(){
     return $(this).text() == "2";
})
```

---

Use the **[`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** method to get the __th element which matches the selector:

```
var divs = $('.content'); // Contains all `.content` elements.
var div2 = divs.eq(2);    // Get the second, returns a jQuery object

// If you want the DOM element:
var div2DOM = divs2[0];   // Alternative method: `divs2.get(0)`
```

Comment: Won't this get the div at index 2 regardless of what text it contains?

Comment: @AbeMiessler Updated answer to reflect the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var myDiv = $('div:contains("2")');
```

Comment: Except this also matches `<div class='content'>12</div>`

Comment: This is true.  It does not perform an exact match.  If he needs that then your method is best.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("div :contains(2)").....
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aTbB5/)

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use the `filter()` command of jQuery. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.content').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == '2'
    }).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```